# fetch image using FormData but don't have image content

Tags: javascript, fetch, multipartform-data

```
const targetFile = e.target.files[0];
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', targetFile)

const res = await fetch('...url', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
  header: {
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
}
```

in browsers's network tab, Payload tab

```
Request Payload:
------WebKitFormBoundary7mRjgSHfZ3oSy0XR
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image-name.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundary7mRjgSHfZ3oSy0XR--
```

this is it! no information about image, nothing more.

Is it normal payload scheme when sending image file???? I highliy doubt that :/

why this is happening?

thanks in advance.